# Automating Software installation in Amazon Windows Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, automated-tests, aws-cli

I would like to use Amazon Windows Instance to test the compatibility of the code which is developed on Mac. I may use the instance once a month for few hours for testing purposes that's it. I don't want my instance running the whole month and costing me.

Hence I am planning to create an instance whenever I want. To test the code I have to install g++, openGL, boost libraries etc. How can do this using scripts?

I am looking for some scripts which install packages on a freshly installed Windows instance, clone the files from git, build and test the software.

For example for AWS Ubuntu instance I can do the following,

```
./> ssh -i KeyPairForUbuntu.pem ubuntu@instance.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com
./> sudo apt install <packages>
./> git clone pathToTheGit
./> run scons scripts to build and run the project
```

Is there any similar way to do this for Windows?

Please give any suggestions,

Thanks

Comment: Downvoters could you please explain to me what went wrong with the question?

Comment: This is a fairly open ended question. You do not indicate what type of packages or give an example of what you want to do, and what  you want the output to look like. @harmoniemand gave an example of a third party app for managing desktop applications.

Comment: Added more details. Now it is more clear than before.

Comment: If I want to create a repeatable process within a windows environment, I end up using Powershell. I manage build environments and much of what I do is configure the build system using powershell scripts. My guess is that all of the pieces you require to configure the build system is contained in source control and all you need is an easy way to create a system every month or two for testing.

Comment: Hi @DanielLee Thanks for the reply. Yes I am right now in creating AMI for a  system which has all the software installed in it. Hope this would work for creating the system every month.

Answer (score 1):

try using https://chocolatey.org/

its a package management like apt-get for windows

Comment: Sorry, I have added more details to my question. Chocolatey has to be installed manually on Windows I guess, in such case, this is not the one I am looking for. Thanks anyway.